# Using Paypal API from server side how can I protect the PAN? or do I just pass it in clear text?

Tags: security, encryption, paypal, pci-compliance

I would like to use the paypal API to perform a payment from server side.
looking at their API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments/#payment.create I willneed to send the credit card number. However this is not PCI compliant,
How can I protect the PAN when I pass it to paypal?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to process direct cards on your website, you will need to be PCI compliant.Look at this [link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/pci_compliant_solution).

Comment: I am in the process of becoming PCI certified. still would like to understand how to pass PAN securely

Answer (score 0):

Per the [PCI DSS 3.1](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf), requirement 4 details what strong cryptography and protocols should be used.  Additionally, within requirement 4.1,

> Sensitive information must be encrypted during
>   transmission over public networks, because it is
>   easy and common for a malicious individual to
>   intercept and/or divert data while in transit.

Therefore, since all SSL and TLS 1.0 implementation are not considered secure, I would suggest encrypting the data via TLS 1.2 when it goes over the intenet by accessing the REST interface via HTTPS and ensuring that TLS 1.2 is used.

Comment: Do you think the PCI DSS treats TLS 1.2 as secure enough or will we need to encrypt the actual content in addition to the protocol?

Comment: The encryption on the transport layer should be enough.  You are sending the data over to another (hopefully) PCI compliant solution, that should have the controls in place regarding when the data needs to be encrypted on their side.  Additionally, a quick look at the API does not show a way of sending keys to the API in a secure manner, which would be necessary to have Paypal decrypt the data.